# How to draw nodes over edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I draw my graph, the edges overlap with some of the nodes. How do I make the nodes on top of the edges instead of the edges on top of the nodes? I tried using the backgrounds package, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code for reference.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary[topaths]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,16}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\x-1)*360/16}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.05cm,minimum width = 13pt,font=\scriptsize] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {$\x$};
  } 
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {1,...,15}{%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,16}{%
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \path (N-\x) edge[ultra thin,-] (N-\y);
    \end{scope}
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just add `fill=white`. -> `\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.05cm,minimum width = 13pt,font=\scriptsize,fill=white] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {$\x$};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the nodes are already in the foreground and the edges on the background (layer). But the nodes themselves have a transparent background. So you can see the edge background behind the nodes. You just have to fill the nodes white to make the background edge invisible:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary[topaths]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,16}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\x-1)*360/16}
    \node[draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0.05cm,minimum width = 13pt,font=\scriptsize] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {$\x$};
  } 
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {1,...,15}{%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,16}{%
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \path (N-\x) edge[ultra thin,-] (N-\y);
    \end{scope}
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get

[image: nodes above edges]

Comment: Thanks! I have been trying to figure this out forever, and the solution was so simple. Edit: It seems like the nodes aren't in the foreground though because if I remove the edges from the background layer, the edges still overlap the nodes. If I leave the edges in the background layer, the solution seems to work.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood what you meant. I get it now.

Comment: @Ralff Added additional explanation to (hopefully) make it more clear.